# Как программно получить размер TextView на kotlin в sp?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview

Подскажите, можно ли программно на языке kotlin получить размеры TextView в sp (in scaled pixels)?
Нужно получить размер TextView, передать его в SharedPreferences и на другом экране у другого TextView извлечь этот размер и присвоить ему (другому TextView).
Получаю размер TextView методом textView.textSize (в логах пишет, что размер равен 140.0, хотя в xml-файле у этого textView размер 70sp). Присваиваю этот размер другому TextView с помощью Preferences, но он получается в 2 раза больше. На Java есть метод getScaledTextSize, который возвращает размер в sp. На котлине такого метода не нашёл, есть только метод textSize(Аналог getTextSize() в java), который возвращает размер в px. Думаю, что проблема в этом, хотя могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Нет никакого метода `getScaledTextSize` в Android SDK, и все что в этом SDK можно вызвать в Java, можно и в Kotlin.

Comment: И правда нет..Странно, а что за метод в классе TextView тогда высвечивается, сразу под getText()?

/**
     * return the size (in scaled pixels) of the default text size in this TextView.
     * @hide
     */
    ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "text")
    public float getScaledTextSize() {
        return mTextPaint.getTextSize() / mTextPaint.density;
    }

Comment: Этот метод помечен аннотацией `@hide`, это означает, что при компиляции SDK он не будет включен в `android.jar`, поэтому в IDE будет недоступен. Но через рефлексию во время исполнения на устройстве к нему добраться можно.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получаете размер вашего текста в пикселях:

```
textView.textSize
```

После чего конвертируете его в SP:

```
val sp = px / resources.displayMetrics.scaledDensity
```

Comment: Спасибо) Всё коротко и ясно!

Comment: Но это же не Котлин :)

Comment: А причем тут котлин?

Comment: Ну вопрос-то звучит однозначно, и в заголовке и по тексту. Но если автор доволен)

Comment: Ну как бы если я напишу тоже самое на котлине то там уберется только несколько скобочек и точек с запятой... Как бы я хз че тут придираться?

Comment: Но если вам так принципиально - я перепишу на Котлин. Так что ставим лайк - подписываемся на канал

Comment: Абсолютно не принципиально) Во-первых, учился я на Java, так что понимаю, о чём речь..А во-вторых, закидываешь код в Студию и она сама всё конвертнёт в Котлин автоматически..делов-то)

Comment: Мне-то одинаково, только выглядит все странно, автор пишет изначально что знает как это в Java делается, но у него проблемы с Котлином. Получает ответ на Java и типа "закидываешь код в Студию" и готово. Так была ли проблема? Возможно была, только пришедшему со стороны трудно понять. А это главное ради чего этот ресурс и существует.